# Getting started with Ettus USRP B200mini and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, usrp, uhd

I'm struggling with an easy task: get USRP B200mini working with my code.

I already wrote do ettus support(mailing list) but, obviusly, nobody answered.

I'm using windows 10 x64 and visual studio 2017, I downloded and compiled boost 1.67.0 (both 32 and 64 bit). I used udh.dll from UHD 3.12.0.0 and GNURadio-3.7.

I followed the simple guide but it's not working, even this small piece code gives me error:

```
 int UHD_SAFE_MAIN(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uhd::set_thread_priority_safe();

    uhd::usrp::subdev_spec_t addr; // <-- exception

 }
```

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9A3321688 (uhd.dll) in
>   ConsoleApplicationTest2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading
>   location 0x000000AC70300000.

Other softwares are working with my device but my code is not, maybe it has an easy solution.. 
Did anyone already faced this issue?

Comment: Which list did you write to? Can't find any trace of an Email from a Bastianon on usrp-users...

Comment: I wrote from bastianonm at gmail on 5 of july. I can't remember the list